# What should someone learn to get into IT Security?

Tags: professional-education, career

I want to learn about security. How to monitor systems, mobile devices, computers etc. What sort of stuff do I need to research to get into my own devices and monitor/change things, be fluent in Linux systems and code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you even remotely attempt to search on the website? There are tons of topics covering this. -1 for lazyness

Comment: One should learn IT Security to get into IT Security.

Comment: Hi Twinborn, welcome to [security.se]. This is not really an answerable question, and as the other commenters noted you can really just wander around this site - it's all about security, and there are many many different areas. There is not just one... However your question does show a bit of confusion regarding what security is. For example, Security != Linux. Security != changing things. And so on... While all those topics are tangentially related to certain fields of security, it is not what security is about.

Comment: Please don't take our closing of this question as a reason to not get into security, though! It's a great field to get into, and is rapidly growing as a business. Join us in [the DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) for a chat some time if you'd like more informal advice.

Comment: I second @Polynomial's invite to the DMZ. Whilst not all of the discussion we have there is... always constructive, you will be able to hopefully get some good advice there. You have the reputation needed (20 is the minimum) so wander in and introduce yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a [Matrix DVD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00000K19E), then burn it as a symbolic gesture. It would be hard to make a better first step into serious IT Security.

(Caution: burn it in an outdoor location. These things contain nasty chemicals !)

Comment: your sarcasm knows no bounds. :)

Comment: Oh Tom, whatever I have done to deserve a [better link](http://www.eapoe.org/works/tales/goldbga2.htm) from you?!? Or you just thought I can't be trusted with matches? :)))